# Angular Router matching paths starting with

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

One requirement for an app I'm working is to support multiple route prefixes.

i.e. `/shop` and `/store` should both be matched. I've achieved this using a custom UrlMatcher:

```
matchPathsStartingWith(startingWith: string[]) {
    return (url: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult => {
      if (url.length) {
        let s = url.map(u => u.path).join('/');
        console.log(s);
        if (startingWith.includes(url[0].path)) {
          return { consumed: url };
        }
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

I use this as follows:

```
  {
    matcher: new UrlPathMatcher().matchPathsStartingWith([
      'store',
      'shop',
    ]),
    loadChildren:
      'app/store.module#StoreModule',
  },
```

Then in my Store Module, I have the following routes defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StoreDashboardComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsListComponent,
  },
];
```

The issue I'm facing is that this only matches the first route (i.e. `StoreDashboardComponent`, but not `ProductsListComponent`. I'm assuming this is due to what is being returned by my custom matcher function.

What should I return to achieve the desired functionality?

Edit: If I get rid of the URLMatcher entirely, and instead create two seperate routes for 'shop' and 'store' it works fine.

Comment: Switch the position of routes. `path: ''` with match first and no other will get routed. That's the most blatant issue I see. `Default` and `Wildcard` routes most be last in the sequence.

Comment: @AndrewLobban That is incorrect. You can have a root path (`''`) before a named path (`'foo'`), and both can still be routed to just fine. What you are referring to happens when you have a path like `':id'` before a named path. In that case, the parameter path will always be routed to and the named path will never be hit.

Comment: Yup, tried switching them around, doesn't solve anything.